# Too few arguments to function when downloading a PDF

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I am trying to generate a PDF with some details of an individual user using the Barryvdh DomPDF library but having some problems trying to generate it.

Controller method:

```php
public function downloadPDF(Card $card)
{
    $user = User::find($card->user_id);

    $pdf = (new \Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF)->loadView('pdf/cardsReport', $user);

    return $pdf->download('cards.pdf');
}
```

Here is how I am referencing the route.

```html
<a href="{{ route('get::admin.download-pdf', ['card' => $profile->card->display()]) }}">Download PDF</a>
```

Route:

```php
$router->get(
    '/downloadPDF/{card}',
    [
        'as' => 'get::admin.download-pdf',
        'uses' => 'EditCardController@downloadPDF',
    ]
);
```

I get this error:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function
> Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::__construct(), 0 passed in EditCardController.php
> and exactly 4 expected.

I'm confused by this as I've seen many samples of using pdf and laravel where you don't need to pass four arguments so was wondering why this would be?

Comment: It's solved now managed to sort it without using DomPDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf), you should use facade instead of constructor:

```php
public function downloadPDF(Card $card)
{
    $user = User::find($card->user_id);

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf/cardsReport', $user);

    return $pdf->download('cards.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kindly use below format**

```
   $data = [
      'title' => 'Welcome to ItSolutionStuff.com',
      'date' => date('m/d/Y'),
   ];
   $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
   $pdf->loadView('bill',$data);
   return $pdf->stream();
```